# I am trying to use easymock to return a list

Tags: junit, powermock, easymock

```
List<ReservationArrival> resArrivalList = new ArrayList<>();

ReservationArrival reservArr = new ReservationArrival();

reservArr.setArrivalStatus("DISPATCHED");
reservArr.setReservationArrivalId(9888888L);
reservArr.setDispatchTime("2018-03-07 17:29:30");


EasyMock.replay( resArrivalList );

expect(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(EasyMock.anyObject(String.class),
        EasyMock.anyObject(MapSqlParameterSource.class),
        EasyMock.anyObject(ReservationArrivalMapper.class))).andReturn(resArrivalList);
```

My mocked object namedParameterJdbcTemplate returns null list

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the mocked service (`namedParameterJdbcTemplate`) into replay mode not the `resArrivalList` which is just a normal object used as a return value by the mock.
Also the replay call have to be after the setup for the mocks.

Something like this should work:

```
List<ReservationArrival> resArrivalList = new ArrayList<>();

ReservationArrival reservArr = new ReservationArrival();

reservArr.setArrivalStatus("DISPATCHED");
reservArr.setReservationArrivalId(9888888L);
reservArr.setDispatchTime("2018-03-07 17:29:30");


expect(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(EasyMock.anyObject(String.class),
        EasyMock.anyObject(MapSqlParameterSource.class),
        EasyMock.anyObject(ReservationArrivalMapper.class))).andReturn(resArrivalList);

EasyMock.replay( namedParameterJdbcTemplate );
```